# How to pick a free port for a subprocess?

Tags: python, linux, macos, networking, network-programming

I am writing a Python wrapper around Appium server. Appium accepts command-line parameter for a local port to bind to. Unfortunately, Appium cannot autoselect a free port for itself, so it either binds to explicitly specified port, or fails with `EADDRINUSE`. Even when telling it to bind to port `0`, it will start successfully, but won't display what port it had bound to.

If I find a free port myself in the Python wrapper, there is no guarantee that some other process won't bind to the same port meanwhile I am passing it to Appium. And if I don't release it first myself, Appium won't be able to bind to it, so I have to.

I know this is unlikely to ever happen in practice, but what would be the "right way" to "reserve" a local port number before passing it to another process in a cross-platform way (Linux, macOS, Windows)?

Comment: You could perhaps pick a random port, pass it to Appium, and check for the right error message.

Comment: Can't you try an arbitrary port, and if it returns `EADDRINUSE` increment it and loop until you find a free one?

Comment: @AlexHall, this is what I am doing now. However, the question is about the "right way" — e.g. is there a way to reserve a port number for a subprocess?

Comment: @rodrigo, this will work if I am the only who is going to use that port. But I want to pass it to Appium, so I will have to release it first, and then, while Appium is starting, some other process may take it (because I am running lots of servers with dynamically allocated ports).

Comment: @toriningen: When I say _pick_ I mean _choose_ not _bind_. If the port is in use when the server is started, increment and repeat. You will eventually get a success unless you are out of free ports.

Comment: @rodrigo, but this implies that I will have to start up heavy server process for each unsuccessful attempt, which is something I try to avoid, and which is what I do now.

Comment: @toriningen: Ah, a heavy server... I actually know nothing about Appium, but I'll advice anyway. If with `0` it starts succesfully, I can think of two solutions: 1. patch Appium to report the port used (it is Open Source after all); 2. Use a command like `lsof -p <pid> -i4 -P -n | grep LISTEN` to discover the port it is using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @rodrigo suggestion in comments, I have ended up with this code:

```
import platform
import re
import subprocess
from typing import Set

if platform.system() == 'Windows':
    def _get_ports(pid):
        sp = subprocess.run(['netstat', '-anop', 'TCP'],
                            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                            stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL,
                            check=True)

        rx_socket = re.compile(br'''(?x) ^
                                    \s* TCP
                                    \s+ 127.0.0.1 : (?P<port>\d{1,5})
                                    \s+ .*?
                                    \s+ LISTENING
                                    \s+ (?P<pid>\d+)
                                    \s* $''')

        for line in sp.stdout.splitlines():
            rxm = rx_socket.match(line)
            if rxm is None:
                continue

            sock_port, sock_pid = map(int, rxm.groups())
            if sock_pid == pid:
                yield sock_port
else:
    def _get_ports(pid):
        sp = subprocess.run(['lsof', '-anlPFn', '+w',
                             f'-p{pid}', '-i4TCP@127.0.0.1', '-sTCP:LISTEN'],
                            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                            stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL,
                            check=True)

        for line in sp.stdout.splitlines():
            if line.startswith(b'n'):
                host, port = line.rsplit(b':', 1)
                port = int(port)
                yield port


def get_ports(pid: int) -> Set[int]:
    """Get set of local-bound listening TCPv4 ports for given process.

    :param pid: process ID to inspect
    :returns: set of ports
    """

    return set(_get_ports(pid))

print(get_ports(12345))
```

It works on Linux, macOS and Windows, and finds out all locally-bound TCPv4 ports for given process that are in LISTEN state. It also skips all kinds of host/port/username reverse look-ups to make it faster, and does not require elevated privileges.

So, finally, the idea is to just let Appium (or anything else) start on `0.0.0.0:0`, it will bind itself to the first available port, as provided by OS, and then inspect what ports is it now listening on. No race conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Selenium library uses this trick:

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/py/selenium/webdriver/common/utils.py#L31

```py
import socket

def free_port():
    """
    Determines a free port using sockets.
    """
    free_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    free_socket.bind(('0.0.0.0', 0))
    free_socket.listen(5)
    port = free_socket.getsockname()[1]
    free_socket.close()
    return port
```

If you bind a socket to port 0, the kernel will assign it a free port. It works for windows and Linux.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737550.aspx

> For TCP/IP, if the port is specified as zero, the service provider 
>      assigns a unique port to the application from the dynamic client port 
>      range.

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ip.7.html

In ip_local_port_range, you can read the following:

> An ephemeral port is allocated to a socket in the following
>     circumstances:
>
> - the port number in a socket address is specified as 0 when
>        calling bind(2);

getsockname() is used to know which port has been picked.

Comment: While this might provide an answer to the question, some explanation is required. Please update the question with some explanation of how and why this solution works.

Comment: Your snippet just chooses first available port, which is not related to the question. The trick is to pass it to the 3rd-party subprocess without introducing race conditions, not just choose the port.