# How to find a free local port using Swift?

Tags: swift, sockets

For a local server I need to specify a port, which must not be in use. There's a really neat [solution in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44875422/how-to-pick-a-free-port-for-a-subprocess) to get a free port. However, such a socket library is not available in Swift. So I tried [Using BSD Sockets in Swift](https://rderik.com/blog/using-bsd-sockets-in-swift/), but that actually wants a port to be specified upfront and I cannot get the `bind` command to work. Here's the code I tried:

```swift
    let socketFD = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if socketFD == -1 {
      print("Error creating BSD Socket")
      return
    }

    var hints = addrinfo(
      ai_flags: AI_PASSIVE,       // Assign the address of the local host to the socket structures
      ai_family: AF_UNSPEC,       // Either IPv4 or IPv6
      ai_socktype: SOCK_STREAM,   // TCP
      ai_protocol: 0,
      ai_addrlen: 0,
      ai_canonname: nil,
      ai_addr: nil,
      ai_next: nil)

    var servinfo: UnsafeMutablePointer<addrinfo>? = nil
    let addrInfoResult = getaddrinfo(
      nil,                        // Any interface
      "8000",                   // The port on which will be listenend
      &hints,                     // Protocol configuration as per above
      &servinfo);

    if addrInfoResult != 0 {
      print("Error getting address info: \(errno)")
      return
    }

    let bindResult = Darwin.bind(socketFD, servinfo!.pointee.ai_addr, socklen_t(servinfo!.pointee.ai_addrlen));
    if bindResult == -1 {
      print("Error binding socket to Address: \(errno)")
      return
    }

    let listenResult = Darwin.listen(socketFD, 1);
    if listenResult == -1 {
      print("Error setting our socket to listen")
      return
    }

    let port = Darwin.getsockname(socketFD, nil, nil);
```

The bind call always returns -1 and since I want to get a free port it makes no sense to specify one in `getaddrinfo`. What's the correct way here?

Comment: The correct solution is to `bind()` to port 0 and let the OS pick a port for you.

Comment: Sure, I know. That's what the python solution does. My question is: how to do that in Swift?

Comment: what happens when you try to specify `”0”` as the port for `getaddrinfo()`? You claim `bind()` returns -1, what does `errno` report as the reason?

Comment: It doesn't change the behavior. `getaddrinfo` still succeeds and `bind` still fails.

Comment: you didn’t answer my question. What does `errno` report as the reason WHY `bind()` fails?

Comment: Error binding socket to Address: 47

Comment: Apparently this means IPv6 is not supported. Changing `ai_family` to `AF_INET` brought me over the bind call. Now I only need to solve the `getsockname` call, which still returns -1.

Comment: even if IPv6 were unsupported, your use of `AF_UNSPEC` should let `getaddrinfo()` use IPv4. Oh well. The reason `getsockname()` fails is because you are setting its parameters to nil. They are output parameters, they can’t be nil. You need to pass in a pointer to a `sockaddr_in` (IPv4) or `sockaddr_in6` (IPv6) to receive the bound interface/port info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a working solution:

```swift
func findFreePort() -> UInt16 {
    var port: UInt16 = 8000;

    let socketFD = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if socketFD == -1 {
      //print("Error creating socket: \(errno)")
      return port;
    }

    var hints = addrinfo(
      ai_flags: AI_PASSIVE,
      ai_family: AF_INET,
      ai_socktype: SOCK_STREAM,
      ai_protocol: 0,
      ai_addrlen: 0,
      ai_canonname: nil,
      ai_addr: nil,
      ai_next: nil
    );

    var addressInfo: UnsafeMutablePointer<addrinfo>? = nil;
    var result = getaddrinfo(nil, "0", &hints, &addressInfo);
    if result != 0 {
      //print("Error getting address info: \(errno)")
      close(socketFD);

      return port;
    }

    result = Darwin.bind(socketFD, addressInfo!.pointee.ai_addr, socklen_t(addressInfo!.pointee.ai_addrlen));
    if result == -1 {
      //print("Error binding socket to an address: \(errno)")
      close(socketFD);

      return port;
    }

    result = Darwin.listen(socketFD, 1);
    if result == -1 {
      //print("Error setting socket to listen: \(errno)")
      close(socketFD);

      return port;
    }

    var addr_in = sockaddr_in();
    addr_in.sin_len = UInt8(MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: addr_in));
    addr_in.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET);

    var len = socklen_t(addr_in.sin_len);
    result = withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &addr_in, {
      $0.withMemoryRebound(to: sockaddr.self, capacity: 1) {
        return Darwin.getsockname(socketFD, $0, &len);
      }
    });

    if result == 0 {
      port = addr_in.sin_port;
    }

    Darwin.shutdown(socketFD, SHUT_RDWR);
    close(socketFD);

    return port;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The above solution has a bug. The port being returned is in network (big-endian) order and needs to be byte swapped on host (small-endian) machines. Another issue is that there is a race condition which could allow the system to return the same port to another process before it is used. This solution mitigates the race (but does not prevent it completely) by forcing the socket into a `TIME_WAIT` state which gives it approximately ~120 seconds depending on the system configuration before it is available to be re-used. The server process which will use the port should set `SO_REUSEADDR` to use it before the time runs out. Most servers already do this.

```swift
/// Reserve an ephemeral port from the system
///
/// First we `bind` to port 0 in order to allocate an ephemeral port.
/// Next, we `connect` to that port to establish a connection.
/// Finally, we close the port and put it into the `TIME_WAIT` state.
///
/// This allows another process to `bind` the port with `SO_REUSEADDR` specified.
/// However, for the next ~120 seconds, the system will not re-use this port.
/// - Returns: A port number that is valid for ~120 seconds.
func reservePort() throws -> UInt16 {
    let serverSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)
    guard serverSock >= 0 else {
        throw ServerError.cannotReservePort
    }
    defer {
        close(serverSock)
    }
    var addr = sockaddr_in()
    addr.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY
    addr.sin_port = 0 // request an ephemeral port

    var len = socklen_t(MemoryLayout<sockaddr_in>.stride)
    let res = withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &addr) {
        $0.withMemoryRebound(to: sockaddr.self, capacity: 1) {
            let res1 = bind(serverSock, $0, len)
            let res2 = getsockname(serverSock, $0, &len)
            return (res1, res2)
        }
    }
    guard res.0 == 0 && res.1 == 0 else {
        throw ServerError.cannotReservePort
    }

    guard listen(serverSock, 1) == 0 else {
        throw ServerError.cannotReservePort
    }

    let clientSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)
    guard clientSock >= 0 else {
        throw ServerError.cannotReservePort
    }
    defer {
        close(clientSock)
    }
    let res3 = withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &addr) {
        $0.withMemoryRebound(to: sockaddr.self, capacity: 1) {
            Darwin.connect(clientSock, $0, len)
        }
    }
    guard res3 == 0 else {
        throw ServerError.cannotReservePort
    }

    let acceptSock = accept(serverSock, nil, nil)
    guard acceptSock >= 0 else {
        throw ServerError.cannotReservePort
    }
    defer {
        close(acceptSock)
    }
    return addr.sin_port.byteSwapped
}

enum ServerError: Error {
    case cannotReservePort
}
```